# regex.replace does not working in pattern with "$" - c#

Tags: c#, regex

I've tried to replace user name in Git's URL, by using `Regex.replace()`.

The reason I want to use `Regex.Replace` instead of `string.Replace` is because I want to replace only the first occurrence.

The expected result is: `"https://******:adss!#&@github.com/test/test.git"`
The actual result is: `"https://#32$3:adss!#&@github.com/test/test.git"`

Unfortunately it's not replaced. The code as bellow:

```
class Program
{
    private static Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?i)(http|https):\/\/(?<UserName>.*):(.*?)@.*\/");
    private const string userNameGroup = "UserName";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = matchRgexWithUserName("https://#32$3:adss!#&@github.com/test/test.git");

        Console.WriteLine(url);
    }

    static string matchRgexWithUserName(string url)
    {
        Match match = reg.Match(url.ToString());

        string username = match.Groups[userNameGroup].Value;
        Regex r = new Regex(username);
        url = r.Replace(url,"******",1);
        return url;
    }
}
```

this line works well:

```
string username = match.Groups[userNameGroup].Value;
```

the problem is with these lines:

```
Regex r = new Regex(username);
        url = r.Replace(url,"******",1);
        return url;
```

I suspect the problem is with the "$". Is there other way to overcome on it?
Thanks!

Comment: Please, try http://regexstorm.net/tester before coding your regex. You can fix it there.

Comment: Any sample of expected input and output + the actual output that you get?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# dollar problem with regex-replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338464/c-sharp-dollar-problem-with-regex-replace)

Comment: Sorry but it's not the same problem. My problem is to replace any user name (not hard-coded) from the url. I'll update my question to explain more the problem.

Comment: you can use this method to escape special characters in regex: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Arie in this case yes, but in general case the escaped string can be found first earlier in the input. Suppose for instance that username is `http`.

Comment: @Arie Can you be more detailed? How to escape the dollar sign? Not sure it can help my case.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work, because `$` is a special character in regex.

To solve the problem, you can put everything before `UserName` and after it into groups too:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?<firstPart>(?i)(http|https):\/\/)(?<UserName>.*)(?<secondPart>:(.*?)@.*\/)");
```

Then you can use `Replace` to combine `firstPart`, `"******"` and `secondPart` - without `UserName`:

```
string result = reg.Replace(url, "${firstPart}******${secondPart}");
```

Basically, you match the url to a `{firstPart}{UserName}{secondPart}` pattern and replace it with `{firstPart}******{secondPart}` (removing the `UserName`).

Comment: This won't work correctly if the `******` contains any dollar signs.

Comment: @JLRishe `"******"` contains only `*`s - that's what the `UserName` group should be replaced with.

Comment: I was figuring that `******` was OP's way of hiding the actual value from us, but you might be right.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Regex.Replace` that way is the wrong way to go about this. Once you know the username, you can use a regular string replace:

```
url = url.Replace("://" + username, "://" + "*****");
```

Comment: but if your user name is same as some folder's name in the path that will be replaced too.